# How to make image inside div tag always a percentage larger than the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently using parallax.js (https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) to get a parallax effect on a hero image on my page. I am trying to use a div tag to use as a "frame" so the image doesn't "appear" floating. I basically want the image to be a percentage larger than the div tag so as the image moves the container is fully covered by the image. [This is what's happening. And not what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJjPH.jpg) Hope this makes sense.

TIA

Here is my code:

```
<div id="scene" data-relative-input="true" class="float-image" style="border: 20px solid red; overflow: hidden;">
                <img src="img/#.jpg" data-depth="0.2" class="cover-img">
                <img src="img/#.png" data-depth="0.1" class="cover-img">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scene {
    position: relative;
}

.cover-img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
 }

.float-image {
z-index: -1;
object-fit: cover;
flex-shrink: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not showing the problem. If insert an image into your current code, it works well and there is no extra indentation. Open the developer tool in your browser and see the reason for these indentations.

Comment: Please provide a JS fiddle

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the problem I am having. https://imgur.com/a/mwCAxgI

Comment: Here's the JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a5ntyL2x/1/